# Flutter TextFormField should give suggestions based on data in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, search-suggestion

Can anybody give me a hint ? If you need further information please write a comment.

Comment: Do you mean something like a autocomplete?

Comment: I invite you to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on StackOverflow, you should always provide some code so people can help you and not waiting for people to ask you for further information.

Comment: Yeah something like autocomplete, i cant provide a code since i dont have any. I just asked for a hint. Like a library or something which can help me. In my application there is an input field which asks for a location. So if the user types in any location, he/she should get suggestions depending on what location he wrote in the past in that input field. I think this is possible because i store already typed in locations in my firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Autocomplete solutions, it's advisable to maintain a master list of all entries and keywords that would be searchable, in practice this can be all stored in an array in a single Firestore document - firestore document restrictions apply. You would maintain this with cloud functions based on your design and potentially cloud triggers.

With the new [Bundle feature](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/04/firestore-supports-data-bundles.html) from Firestore, you can allow every client to have direct access to this information, it's only up to you to process the search input and compare it to the master document.